R arrow package: Read CSV file with number with negative sign on the right, "," as decimal mark and "." as grouping mark
I have a big txt file with the following structure:
text01|number01|number02|number03
txt1|1.000,37|1.000,73-|-1.000,37

In R i would like to read it with the arrow package, especially with the read_delim_arrow function.
The function read the file but doesn't recognize the columns 2:4 as numbers.
Which is the best way to read numbers formatted as indicated?
The script I used is the following:
read_delim_arrow(file = "./Dati/esempio.txt", delim = "|", decimal_point = ",")

I would like to use arrow because the file is big. The arrow's function open_delim_dataset could be better because the entire dataset could be bigger than RAM.
Thanks
Domenico M

In your example the minus sign is both on the left and right? So it can be either? What software produces this file format?

Well, really i have 2 file to import, one from an app with the minus sign on the right and the other one from a second app with the minus on the left side; as i don't know to deal with the minus and i did't find documentation about it, i put all in 1 example.

What is the expected structure and contents of the data you provided? In other words, what are the values for number01, number02, and number03?

The columuns from 2 to 4 should be read as number and not as character. Imported in a R dataframe, they should look like:
txt1 1000.37 -1000.73 -1000.37
As I see, the problems are:
1 Grouping mark. Removing it, arrow detect automatically number01 and number03 as numbers.
2 Minus sign on the right. Also removing manually the grouping mark in a test file, number02 is imported as char.
Manual editing of the production files is non possibile.


Manual editing of the production files is non possibile.

We needn't do the editing manually; instead of "./Dati/esempio.txt" as the file argument we can use
pipe("sed 's/\\([0-9]\\)\\.\\([0-9]\\)/\\1\\2/g;s/\\([0-9,]*\\)-/-\\1/g' Dati/esempio.txt")

to remove the grouping mark and to move the minus sign to the left.

Works. A solution offered by the arrow importer (read_delim_arrow) could be preferable, but your script does the job. Thanks

I agree, but see no solution offered by the arrow importer.
